# How can I pass variables to function from onClick in Meteor/React?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I have some code like so

```
goToEvent() {
  FlowRouter.go('/event/${id}');
}

return (
  {e.users.map( (id) => {
    <ListItem key={id} primaryText="Event" onClick={this.goToEvent.bind(this)} />
  })}
);
```

I'm unsure how to get the id parameter into the `goToEvent()`.

I actually have the bind in the constructor so I tried having `onClick={this.goToEvent(id)}` but realized that was incorrect because it was calling the method immediately.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: try this `this.goToEvent.bind(this, id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For react the solution is

```
return (
  {e.users.map( (id) => {
    <ListItem key={id} primaryText="Event" onClick={this.goToEvent.bind(this, id)} />
  })}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
onClick={this.goToEvent.bind(this,id)}
```

and in function pass id like this

```
goToEvent(id) {
  FlowRouter.go('/event/${id}');
}
```